# How to slide / swipe / screen edge swipe between two UIViews in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have two UIViews - UIView1 and UIView2 in one UIViewController, both same size (about half screen) and at same location with UIView1 visible and on top of UIView2.

I want to be able to swipe UIView1 left to right to display UIView2, with transition effect smooth like Safari back / forward swipe in iPhone.

Also on reverse I want to be able to swipe UIView2 right to left to display UIView1, with transition effect smooth like Safari back / forward swipe in iPhone.

How do I do this? I saw several examples for the complete UIViewcontroller (using push segue), but couldn't figure  just UIViews.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you have to use 'UIView's instead of 'UIViewController's

Comment: pe60t0, yes I want to use UIView, as I dont want the whole view to be swiped away. I just want top half of the view (that has UIView1 and UIView2) to be able to 'swipeable'. If you have any other recommendations other than UIView please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use this awesome iOS library that does exactly what you are looking to do: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel.

Comment: Would prefer a solution with something native like UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer, if possible

Comment: Then you should post your code. One thing to note is that UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer only works on iOS7 and later. It's best practice when coding on the iPhone to leverage the work of other developers. And by the way most of these libraries are in "native".

Answer (score 0):

iCarousel would fit for this work, but I suggest you to use this solution:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView

It's feels more like native UIScrollView's paging animation.